# How to fix error "The remote procedure call failed" in C# - connecting to scanner

Tags: c#, scanning

I’m trying to scan a paper with scanner and store it. I’m using C# , WIA , Kodak scaner i1310.

I get   **The remote procedure call failed(0x800706be)** error when this line executes : `var imageFile = (ImageFile)scannerItem.Transfer(FormatID.wiaFormatJPEG);`

and here is my code :

```
private void btnScan1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    var deviceManager = new DeviceManager();

    DeviceInfo firstScannerAvailable = null;

    for (int i = 1; i <= deviceManager.DeviceInfos.Count; i++)
    {

        if (deviceManager.DeviceInfos[i].Type != WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType)
        {
            continue;
        }

        firstScannerAvailable = deviceManager.DeviceInfos[i];

        break;
    }


    var device = firstScannerAvailable.Connect();


    var scannerItem = device.Items[1];

    var   imageFile = (ImageFile)scannerItem.Transfer(FormatID.wiaFormatJPEG);

    var path = @"C:\Documents\scan.png";

    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        File.Delete(path);
    }
    imageFile.SaveFile(path);
}
```

can any body help me?

Comment: Seems to be C# instead of VB.Net. Please change your tag.

Comment: Seen things like this? https://answers.laserfiche.com/questions/120295/ScanConnect-Crash - i googled for "kodak 0x800706be"

Comment: dear Caius, thanks for your help but after checking the link and following the instructions i still have same error